# Resume async task before all tasks are started

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

In the example code here all asyncio tasks are started first. After that the tasks are resumed if the IO operation is finished.

The output looks like this where you can see the 6 result messages **after** the first 6 start messages.

```
-- Starting https://jamanetwork.com/rss/site_3/67.xml...
-- Starting https://www.b-i-t-online.de/bitrss.xml...
-- Starting http://twitrss.me/twitter_user_to_rss/?user=cochranecollab...
-- Starting http://twitrss.me/twitter_user_to_rss/?user=cochranecollab...
-- Starting https://jamanetwork.com/rss/site_3/67.xml...
-- Starting https://www.b-i-t-online.de/bitrss.xml...
28337 size for http://twitrss.me/twitter_user_to_rss/?user=cochranecollab
28337 size for http://twitrss.me/twitter_user_to_rss/?user=cochranecollab
1938204 size for https://www.b-i-t-online.de/bitrss.xml
1938204 size for https://www.b-i-t-online.de/bitrss.xml
38697 size for https://jamanetwork.com/rss/site_3/67.xml
38697 size for https://jamanetwork.com/rss/site_3/67.xml
FINISHED with 6 results from 6 tasks.
```

But what I would expect and what whould speed up the thing in my cases is something like this

```
-- Starting https://jamanetwork.com/rss/site_3/67.xml...
-- Starting https://www.b-i-t-online.de/bitrss.xml...
-- Starting http://twitrss.me/twitter_user_to_rss/?user=cochranecollab...
1938204 size for https://www.b-i-t-online.de/bitrss.xml
-- Starting http://twitrss.me/twitter_user_to_rss/?user=cochranecollab...
28337 size for http://twitrss.me/twitter_user_to_rss/?user=cochranecollab
28337 size for http://twitrss.me/twitter_user_to_rss/?user=cochranecollab
-- Starting https://jamanetwork.com/rss/site_3/67.xml...
38697 size for https://jamanetwork.com/rss/site_3/67.xml
-- Starting https://www.b-i-t-online.de/bitrss.xml...
28337 size for http://twitrss.me/twitter_user_to_rss/?user=cochranecollab
28337 size for http://twitrss.me/twitter_user_to_rss/?user=cochranecollab
1938204 size for https://www.b-i-t-online.de/bitrss.xml
38697 size for https://jamanetwork.com/rss/site_3/67.xml
FINISHED with 6 results from 6 tasks.
```

In my real world code I have hundreds of download tasks like this. It is usual that some of the downloads are finished before all of them are started.

Is there a way to handle this with `asyncio`?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
import urllib.request
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
urls = ['https://www.b-i-t-online.de/bitrss.xml',
        'https://jamanetwork.com/rss/site_3/67.xml',
        'http://twitrss.me/twitter_user_to_rss/?user=cochranecollab']

async def parse_one_url(u):
    print('-- Starting {}...'.format(u))
    r = await loop.run_in_executor(executor,
                                   urllib.request.urlopen, u)
    r = '{} size for {}'.format(len(r.read()), u)
    print(r)

async def do_async_parsing():
    tasks = [
        parse_one_url(u)
        for u in urls
            ]

    completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks)
    results = [task.result() for task in completed]

    print('FINISHED with {} results from {} tasks.'
          .format(len(results), len(tasks)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # blow up the urls
    urls = urls * 2
    random.shuffle(urls)
    try:
        #loop.set_debug(True)
        loop.run_until_complete(do_async_parsing())
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

*Side-Question*: Isn't `asyncio` useless in my case? Isn't it easier to use mutliple threads only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my real world code I have hundreds of download tasks like this. It is usual that some of the downloads are finished before all of them are started.

Well, you did create all the downloads upfront and instructed asyncio to launch them all using [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait). Just starting to execute a coroutine is almost free, so there is no reason for this part to be limited in any way. However, the tasks actually submitted to [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) *are* capped to the number of workers in the pool, the default being 5 times the number of CPUs, but configurable. If the number of URLs exceeds the number of workers, you should get the desired behavior. (But to actually observe it, you need to move the logging prints into the function managed by the executor.)

Note that the synchronous call to `r.read()` must also reside inside the function run by the executor, otherwise it will block the entire event loop. The corrected portion of the code would look like this:

```
def urlopen(u):
    print('-- Starting {}...'.format(u))
    r = urllib.request.urlopen(u)  # blocking call
    content = r.read()             # another blocking call
    print('{} size for {}'.format(len(content), u))

async def parse_one_url(u):
    await loop.run_in_executor(executor, urlopen, u)
```

The above is, however, not idiomatic use of asyncio. Normally the idea is that you don't use threads at all, but call natively async code, for example using [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Then you get the benefits of asyncio, such as working cancellation and scalability to a large number of tasks. In that setup you would limit the number of concurrent tasks by trivially wrapping the retrieval in an [`asyncio.Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore).

If your whole actual logic consists of synchronous calls, you don't need asyncio at all; you can directly submit futures to the executor and use [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) synchronization functions like [`wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait) and [`as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed) to wait for them to finish.

Comment: I blow up the urls to `245 * 1150 = 281750`. All of them are started before any of the results are printed to `stdout`. In my real world example is `aiohttp` not a choice because the 3rd-party package I use is using blocking IO.

Comment: Ok, I got it. _Starting_ does not mean that `feedparser.parse()` is called. But exactly that is my problem. It should be called before all tasks are started.

Comment: @buhtz Ok, the problem is one of methodology. Your logging print is not in the method that is actually submitted to the thread pool, but in the coroutine. If you [move them](https://pastebin.com/8QB3BFGM), you get the expected output. I've amended the answer accordingly.